# How can the can the following code be updated to prevent the NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, .net

I get this question during an interview and I have no idea how to resolve it. I answered this is impossible to do but actually I don't know.

*Without modifying any of the code inside the main method*, how can the can the following code be updated to prevent the NullReferenceException and also write 'Hello World' to the consol?

```
public class MyClass
{
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyClass myObj = null;
        Console.WriteLine(myObj.GetString()); // Will throw NullReferenceException 
    }
}
```

What is the solution to this question? I aks this here because I'm really curious of the solution and I wasn't able to answer it myself. Most of comments here are wrong. I tried to solve it but I don't see the solution (if a solution exist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be really bad practice, and there's no good reason to do this, but you could probably add a static constructor to `MyClass` and then exit the code right away.

In general, it would be very bad practice to make code that makes calling a method on a null value *not* cause an exception. Finding why it *didn't* cause an error would be very confusing. This question could be good for language comprehension, but the functionality it describes shouldn't be done.

```
public class MyClass
{
     static MyClass()
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
          System.Environment.Exit(0);
     }
}
```

The static constructor for `MyClass` will be called as soon as a `MyClass` is used. This answers the question, as it writes "Hello World" and then exits before going any further in the `main` method.

Comment: In addition, tell your professor that that code doesn't compile as it is, because `MyClass` doesn't have `GetString()` defined.

Comment: Also, whoever is downvoting: are downvoting because we answered a downvoted question?

Comment: "Without modifying any of the code inside the main method".

Comment: i didn't change any code in the main method, what? i didn't include the whole source code, if you're implying that i omitted it.

Comment: To me it seems like a really wrong thing to completely bypass the `main` function, which this seems to do.

Comment: did you read the question? It specifically says that we cannot modify the `main` function. This answer is, like I said, very bad practice, but is a completely valid answer. It's also very bad practice to add anything that makes working with an object that is null to _not_ cause a nullref exception.

Comment: I bet you are also under the impression I've downvoted you. I'm not saying either of the answer are _wrong_, I just don't think they are a good idea or completely explained.

Comment: Thank you @DLeh. I think the question has been downvoted because I mentioned it was an exam question and these guy wasn't able to find a correct answer. Your answer is bad practice but is correct. Than you.

Answer (score 3):

To solve the puzzle, one can use an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx).

```
public static class Extension
{
    public static string GetString(this MyClass myObj)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even if you use an extension method, you still have to check if the object is null, or else you will get a NRE if you use it, such as calling it's GetString method.

Comment: It works because you are not using myObj in your extension method. Extension methods work even if the associated object is null. But if you wish to use the object, check to make sure it's not null before you use it. However, you are not using myObj, you are only returning a literal string.

Comment: @gunr2171 Of course, I'm not using `myObj. ...`. I think this is a little C# brainteaser, not a practical coding exercize.

Comment: @gunr2171 this is not true, creating an extension method does work in this case, You can call extension methods on null valued objects. You should check your work before criticizing people who are trying to help you.

Comment: @B413 Thanks for the question! I found it quite entertaining :).

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a static member GetString() to the class? Something like...

```
public class MyClass
{
  public static string GetString()
  {
    return "Hello World";
  }
}
```

Comment: Compilation will fail. Static method cannot be accessed with `myObj.GetString`.